Spark doesn't recognize not null fields while reading from the source
I'm trying to read data from database and then save it to parquet file using Kotlin and Apache Spark.
JDBC Driver I use: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 val customerDf = spark
        .read()
        .jdbc(
            "jdbc:mysql://$host:$port/$database",
            "t_customer",
            props)

After loading the data and checking the schema, it turns out that all fields allow null values, even though the table definition clearly imposes NOT NULL contraints. I fixed it by adding the following line:
val schemaCustomerDf = spark.createDataFrame(customerDf.toJavaRDD(), Customer.SCHEMA)

Parquet DDL:
    required int32 id
    required binary name (STRING)
    optional binary name_2 (STRING)
    required binary surname (STRING)
    required binary gender (STRING)
    required binary email_address (STRING)
    optional binary phone_number (STRING)
    required int32 date_birth (DATE)
    required int32 date_join (DATE)
    required binary address_street (STRING)
    optional binary address_street2 (STRING)
    required binary address_city (STRING)
    required binary address_state (STRING)
    required binary address_postal_code (STRING)
    required binary address_country_iso_2 (STRING)

However, after reading the data again, this time from the previously saved parquet file, all fields are nullable again.
Is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong?
I tried to force the schema defined in the Customer class, but I don't think that's the way to go because parquet files store metadata about the schema.

you can create a case class representing your customer and use Dataset[Customer] instead of DataFrame, it would ensure non nullable fields

Of course I can. Unfortunately, this still doesn't explain why the schema isn't read properly when reading a parquet file.

@Devyl I've tried using case class Customer but still it ignores nullability :/
